# Resolving merge conflict with Beyond Compare (Mercurial)

Tags: mercurial, merge, beyondcompare, beyondcompare3

I am using Mercurial and it's configured to open Beyond Compare when there is a conflict when merging.  BC opens just fine and shows me the two files, but I have no idea what to do after that.

Normally in BC there are arrows next to the lines which differ where you can click on them to move the selection to the left or the right.  No matter how I select a section I can not move code from one side to the other, or select a specific section as the one I want to keep.  This UI is very consing.  I basiclly can see the differences but don't know how to tell BC which one I want to keep.

Comment: I haven't used Beyond Compare, but the screenshot looks similar to kdiff3 - you should see three files in the top half of the screen (original version, your edits and incoming changes) and use those to generate a merged version in the bottom half of the screen. If you're not seeing that then I can only assume that there's a problem with your configuration.

Comment: It shows two files (one on the left half of the screen and another on the right).  There is no real final merge section like there is in kdiff3.

Comment: Does your `.hgrc` include `bcomp.args = $local $other $base $output`? That is part of what you need for BC to perform a *three*-way merge.

Comment: You're opening your files in the 2-way file compare, rather than the 3-way merge interface.  Either VonC is right that you don't have it set up correctly, or Tim is that you aren't using the Pro edition.  If neither of those helps you should email support@scootersoftware.com;  they'll be able to provide more directed help than StackOverflow does.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To perform a 3-way merge with Beyond Compare, you must have the ["Pro" version](http://www.scootersoftware.com/shop.php?zz=kb_editions).  The "Standard" version does not support the feature.

Do you know which one you have?

Comment: It doesn't say "Pro" anywhere, so I assume I have the standard version (we have a company license).

Comment: I went with KDiff3 instead, it worked marvelously.  Open source software for the win!

Comment: If you have Pro, you should see it in the about-box, in the white box listing your license details, last line.